# What is the error i'm making that is stopping me from accessing object properties?

Tags: javascript, html

I've run into a problem that I can't figure out myself. My assignment is to:

1. create onload event handler init()
2. in init(), create 3 javascript objects each with the same 6 properties (pertinent one is Price)
3. initialize the values of the properties of each of the 3 objects
4. create an HTML page with 3 buttons (one for each type of object). these buttons will each have an onclick event activating an event handler called "getPrice"
5. create a div for output text
6. in the JS event handler, code it up so that the output text will show the name of the button clicked and the corresponding price

My major problem is that I can't understand how to pull the Price property from the objects. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<input id="btnKoalas" type="button" name="Koalas" value="Koalas" onclick="getPrice()"/>
<input id="btnTulips" type="button" name="Tulips" value="Tulips" onclick="getPrice()"/>
<input id="btnPenguins" type="button" name="Penguins" value="Penguins" onclick="getPrice()"/>

<br />

<p id="divText">This is the output text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my javascript

```
function init()
{

function Koala(ProdID, SupplierCode, Description, PictureName, QtyOnHand, Price) {
    this.ProdID = ProdID;
    this.SupplierCode = SupplierCode;
    this.Description = Description;
    this.PictureName = PictureName;
    this.QtyOnHand = QtyOnHand;
    this.Price = Price;
}

function Tulip(ProdID, SupplierCode, Description, PictureName, QtyOnHand, Price) {same as above}

function Penguin(ProdID, SupplierCode, Description, PictureName, QtyOnHand, Price) {same as above}

}


objKoala = new Koala('1002', 'S1001', 'Koalas', 'Koala.jpg', '9', '119.95');

objTulip = new Tulip('1003', 'S1002', 'Tulips', 'Tulip.jpg', '9', '7.95');

objPenguin = new Penguin('1004', 'S1003', 'Penguins', 'Penguin.jpg', '9', '127.95');


function getPrice()
{
    var output = objKoala.Price;
    //i know this ^ isn't right.. i'm floundering trying to directly pull the data from my object above and it's still not displaying it
    document.getElementById('divText').innerHTML = output;
}
```

i thought i had established my objects as global but when i click my button, nothing happens. How can i pass parameters to the getPrice() function to pull the properties through? Am i making a mistake in the way i am creating my objects?

Comment: You should get an error when you do `objKoala = new Koala()` because Koala is undefined. In javascript functions defined inside other functions have local scope, not global. Therefore there is not function `Koala` outside of the `init()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of that body onload. I moved the event listener into the js itself. And this will also work for all animals. Notice the this.name in the price function. That should take the button's name attribute and access it's respective property without you having to sent it as a parameter.

```
var animals = {};

function init() {

    // The event listeners for each button
    document.getElementById('btnKoalas').addEventListener('click', getPrice);
    document.getElementById('btnTulips').addEventListener('click', getPrice);
    document.getElementById('btnPenguins').addEventListener('click', getPrice);

    // We don't need to do it in here, we can also put it outside.
    animals.Koala = new Koala('1002', 'S1001', 'Koalas', 'Koala.jpg', '9', '119.95');
    animals.Tulip = new Tulip('1003', 'S1002', 'Tulips', 'Tulip.jpg', '9', '7.95');
    animals.Penguin = new Penguin('1004', 'S1003', 'Penguins', 'Penguin.jpg', '9', '127.95');
}


function Koala(ProdID, SupplierCode, Description, PictureName, QtyOnHand, Price) {
    this.ProdID = ProdID;
    this.SupplierCode = SupplierCode;
    this.Description = Description;
    this.PictureName = PictureName;
    this.QtyOnHand = QtyOnHand;
    this.Price = Price;
}

function Tulip(ProdID, SupplierCode, Description, PictureName, QtyOnHand, Price) {same as above}

function Penguin(ProdID, SupplierCode, Description, PictureName, QtyOnHand, Price) {same as above}

// This gets called when the user clicks the button
function getPrice() {

    // 'this' here is the element that was clicked, which can be any of the 3 buttons
    // And we can dynamically access the animal based on the name attribute of the currently clicked button
    var output = animals[this.name].Price;

    document.getElementById('divText').innerHTML = output;
}

// We wait for the window to load, inline event listeners like '<body onload="">' are a bad idea 
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

And the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="btnKoalas" type="button" name="Koala" value="Koalas"/>
<input id="btnTulips" type="button" name="Tulip" value="Tulips"/>
<input id="btnPenguins" type="button" name="Penguin" value="Penguins"/>

<br />

<p id="divText">This is the output text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THANK YOU this is really interesting. appreciate your time!

Comment: Np, Just added comments to explain stuff

Comment: ok so i went through and read it all to make sure i understand and... it's not working. when i run it in internet explorer i get this error:

Line: 43
Error: Unable to get property 'Price' of undefined or null reference

any suggestions? i'm repeatedly checking for typos...

Comment: It would help to see your exact code? Edit: Ah ok never mind, your name attribute and the object you create need to be the same name. So name="Koala", I'll fix it in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The functions `Koala`, `Tulip` and `Penguin` are scoped inside the `init` function, and can not be accessed outside it. The `init` function doesn't really do anything in particular so you could just as well move these outside.

(Also, the code inside the `init()` function only runs after the page has loaded, but `new Koala` etc. runs *immediately*  as the script is loading, i.e., before the `Koala` function has been defined inside `init()`. But as I said, since `Koala` isn't accessible from outside `init()`, this doesn't even matter here.)

When you drop the `init()` function, your code should work fine:

```js
// NOTE: no init() here, so Koala, Tulip, Penguin are globally declared

function Koala(ProdID, SupplierCode, Description, PictureName, QtyOnHand, Price) {
    this.ProdID = ProdID;
    this.SupplierCode = SupplierCode;
    this.Description = Description;
    this.PictureName = PictureName;
    this.QtyOnHand = QtyOnHand;
    this.Price = Price;
}
// etc.

objKoala = new Koala('1002', 'S1001', 'Koalas', 'Koala.jpg', '9', '119.95');
// etc.

function getPrice()
{
    var output = objKoala.Price;
    document.getElementById('divText').innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<input id="btnKoalas" type="button" name="Koalas" value="Koalas" onclick="getPrice()"/>
<!-- etc. -->

<br />

<p id="divText">This is the output text</p>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i'm about to try. What could possibly be the reasoning for my instructor's question to put the objects inside the init() function? my understanding was that, as it is an onload in the html, as soon as the page loads, it will create those objects. Is that just completely unnecessary? Meaning, if i want this functionality, there's no reason to do it that way?

Comment: @grcHIDDEN `onload` is run *after* the page has completely loaded, while the script itself loads as soon as it occurs in the HTML (in other words, it runs *while* the page is loading). There are times when you would want to do things inside an `init()` function like that, but you generally want to declare functions outside it.

Comment: So how would i now go about passing an argument to my getPrice() in my HTML so that i don't have to hardcode the value in? Meaning, when i push each button, the getPrice() function will look for that object's price.

Comment: @grcHIDDEN I would give in an argument to the `getPrice` function that describes what object to look for.